# How to solve this loan lending optimization problem?

Tags: probability, optimization, conditional-probability

I'm trying to model a certain problem in loan lending, and was hoping to get some inputs:

A lender lends amount P to a borrower. The borrower has to repay this loan in $t$ equal monthly installments (EMI) at some annual interest rate $I$.

The EMI is calculated as:

$$E = \dfrac{P \times I}{12(1-(1+\frac{I}{12})^{-t})}$$

Now, there is a chance that the borrower may default payments, so taking this into consideration, the EMI for a month $i$ would be defined as:

$$E(i) = \begin{cases}
0,& \Pr(default|i) > 0.5\\
E,& \Pr(default|i) <=0.5
\end{cases}
$$

For the lender, the value of each successive EMI decreases over time due to inflation. The value $v_i$ for a month $i$ is defined as:

$$v_i = \dfrac{E(i)}{(1+d)^{i}}$$, where $d \in (0,1)$ is fixed.

By setting $t$ and $I$, the lender wishes to maximize net value, which is defined as:

$$NV = \sum_{i=1}^{t} v_i$$

subject to the constraints: $$t \in \{24,36,48,60\}\\
                            I \in (0.13,0.19)$$

My questions are:

1. Is there a term for these kind of optimization problems?
2. How should the lender choose $t$ and $I$ so as to maximize for $NV$ subject to the above constraints? I'm very unfamiliar with optimization 
   problems, so any help is appreciated.
3. Assuming you have some data about the borrower, what are some starting points for estimating the probability in $E(i)$?

Comment: Your $E(i)$ is strange.  Usually it would be $E$ times one minus the probability of default.  If the probability of default is $0.1$ in a given month, the expectation of that month is $0.9E$, not $E$ as you have it.

Comment: The optimization here is simple.  The lender wants the highest interest rate it can get.  If $E(i)$ is fixed, the lender will want the longest term as long as the interest is greater than the discount rate and the expected losses.  If the lender is making money, it wants to have the money loaned out as long as possible.

Comment: @RossMillikan: But if it's likely that the borrower will default often, then increasing the term will be a loss for the lender (since he could have invested the money elsewhere), isn't it?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: $I$ belongs to an interval in $\mathbb R$, so there are infinitely many values.

Comment: Unless raising the interest causes default to be more likely, how can it hurt?  Take all you can get.  The interest has to be enough to cover the probability of default.  You have not included the things that make the optimization hard, like the market forces and how the probability of default depends on the term.

Comment: My bad. In this case, for any fixed $t$, assuming you know how to calculate $E(i)$, the problem becomes a simple single variable optimization problem (which can be dealt with, say, calculus).  Find the best $I$ for each $t$ and pick the best among the best.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ah, I see! It's my first foray into modelling, and I guess I haven't thought things through. Could you point me to some resources that model these kind of "loan value maximization" problems, that also take into account the complex factors that you've mentioned? I'm not sure what's the term to search for such models.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Ah, yes indeed. Thank you!

Comment: In these problems there needs to be something that pushes in both directions.  The classic what price should I charge to maximize profit usually has more sales at lower prices and more unit profit at higher prices, so there is an optimum in between.  That is why I suggested market pricing or higher default at higher interest rates.  Otherwise there is no reason not to charge the maximum interest.